# PHP: How to walk through string while randomly replacing terms?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have a string that's a piece of text like this:

```
$input = AAAA BBBB CCCC DDD E FFFF GGG AAAA HHHH IIII JJJ KKKK
```

I also have a array like this:

```
$terms[0][0] = "AAAA";
$terms[0][1] = "KKKK";
$terms[0][2] = "A2A2";
$terms[1][0] = "FFFF";
$terms[1][1] = "TTT";
$terms[1][2] = "FFF1";
```

These values are not real nor important. This array is made of synonyms. This means that all of `$terms[0]` keys have the same meaning. My whole point here is to randomly replace matches in `$string` with a synonym from the same `$term` key, for example:

```
$output == KKKK BBBB CCCC DDD E FF1F GGG A2A2 HHH III JJJ AAAA
```

or

```
$output == A2A2 BBBB CCCC DDD E TTT GGG KKKK HHH III JJJ AAAA
```

or

```
$output == A2A2 BBBB CCCC DDD E FFF1 GGG KKKK HHH III JJJ A2A2
```

How can I do this?

All I've managed to do is looping through $terms[][] and building a `replace_pairs` array for each match with random values from the same previous key and using `strtr()` afterwards like this:

```
$replace_pairs[AAAA] = "KKKK";
$replace_pairs[FFFF] = "TTT";
$replace_pairs[KKKK] = "A2A2";
$output = strtr($input, $replace_pairs);
```

However, this replaces **all** equal matches (in this example, AAAA to KKKK), to the same value, like this:

```
$output == KKKK BBBB CCCC DDD E TTTF GGG KKKK HHH III JJJ A2A2
```

Is there any way to replace while "walking through" the string so I can always grab a new random element from the synonym's array? Keep in mind that the synonym's also have different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with `array_*` and lambda functions:

```
<?php

// This is the same format of your $terms array.    
$synonyms   = array(
    array(
        'have','possess'
    ),
    array(
        'nice','good','wonderful','pleasurable',
    ),
    array(
        'day','tide','period',
    )
);

$input = "have a nice day.\n";

function synonymize($input, $synonyms) {

    // Replace each word (word-boundary word-characters word-boundary)
    return preg_replace_callback('#\\b(\\w+)\\b#', function($matches) 
        use ($synonyms) {

        $word   = $matches[1];

        // Find what synonyms, if any, this word has.
        $poss   = array_filter($synonyms, function($candidates) use ($word) {
            return in_array($word, $candidates);
        });

        // If none, we can't replace.
        if (empty($poss)) {
            return $word;
        }

        $among  = array_pop($poss);

        // Otherwise return the alternative.

        $newword = $among[rand(0, count($among)-1)];
        // log("replacing {$word} with {$newword}");
        return $newword;

    },
    $input);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) { print synonymize($input, $synonyms); }
?>
```

Yields:

```
have a pleasurable day.
have a nice day.              // Note: null substitution.
possess a wonderful tide.
possess a wonderful period.
possess a good period.
possess a nice tide.
have a nice period.           // Note: poor choice of synonyms.
have a pleasurable day.       // Note: repetition (of course).
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$input = "AAAA BBBB CCCC DDD E FFFF GGG AAAA HHHH IIII JJJ KKKK";
$terms[0][0] = "AAAA";
$terms[0][1] = "KKKK";
$terms[0][2] = "A2A2";
$terms[1][0] = "FFFF";
$terms[1][1] = "TTT";
$terms[1][2] = "FFF1";

$inputarr = explode(" ", $input);
$outputarr = array();
foreach($inputarr as $num => $element){
    $outputarr[$num] = $element;
    foreach($terms as $keys){
        if (in_array($element, $keys)){
            $outputarr[$num] = $keys[rand(0,(count($keys) - 1))];
            break 1;
        }
    }
}
$output = implode(" ", $outputarr);
```